# Getting state from root component - react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, jsx

I am at the very beginning of learning react and I need too take state from root component to the child of a child, I can say.
I have got App.js file, which has state, that is an array of players.
Then I have got Home.js, that I import to App.js, and then I have a Players.js component that needs to display that players object.

/* App.js */

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    players: [
      {name: 'Kacper', gender: 'M', id: 1},
      {name: 'Patrycja', gender: 'F', id: 2},
      {name: 'Marcel', gender: 'M', id: 3},
      {name: 'Wiktoria', gender: 'F', id: 4}
    ]
  }

  deletePlayer = (id) => {

    const players = this.state.players.filter(player => {
      return player.id !== id
    })

    this.setState({
      players
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
     <div>
       <Home players={this.state.players} deletePlayer={this.deletePlayer}/>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

/* Home.js */

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    players: players
  }

  render(){
    return (
     <div className="add-players">
      <Players players={this.state.players}/>
      <div className="add-player"></div>
        <button className="start-btn">
        <i className="material-icons">play_arrow</i> <p>Let's play!</p>
        </button>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

/* Players.js */

```
const Players = ({players, deletePlayer}) => {
  const playerList = players.length ? (
    players.map(player => {
      return (
        <div className="player" key={player.id}>
          <div className="gender">{player.gender}</div>
          <span>{player.name}</span>
          <i className="material-icons" onClick={() => {deletePlayer(player.id)}}>close</i>
        </div>
      )
    })
  ) : (
    <p>Add player</p>
  )
  return (
      <div className="players">
        {playerList}
      </div>
  )
}

export default Players;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed down the root-component's player-state as a property to `Home`. So you have to access it from `props`.

Just update your `Home` component to the following:

```
class Home extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
     <div className="add-players">
      <Players players={this.props.players}/>
      <div className="add-player"></div>
        <button className="start-btn">
        <i className="material-icons">play_arrow</i> <p>Let's play!</p>
        </button>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: So that's easy like that... Thank you so much.